# Trying to handle dynamcialy created links with JS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a gallery of products that is dynamically created using php and mysql on the load of my htlml page.  I am to take all of the images in the gallery, and turn them into links that will produce a modal window with content that is dynamically generated depending on which product is clicked.

My first thought is to use Jquery to select all of products, place an `<a><a/>` around each  image and pass some kind of identifier to the my php that will generate the content in the modal window.  is this thought process correct for trying to achieve this, or is there a better way to look at accomplishing this.  Can any one provide some sample code that i can look at for direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you're describing will work.

However, I'd suggest you generate the wrapping `<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>` in php and leave jQuery to handle only the click events, which would look something like:

```
$('a.product').click(function () {
    $.get('/some/url.php', data: {id: 1234}, function (data) {
        // Request is sent to /some/url.php?id=1234
        // PHP responds with some HTML
        // Output the HTML somewhere
        $('#output').html(data);
    });
});
```

If you're using a library for the modal, some of them support AJAX loading of content already, so you don't need the `$.get`, but instead just supply it a URL and the query params.

Comment: if you are dynamically loading in your elements, you should use `.live`.  If you use just a `.click`, then that click won't bind to any new content.

Comment: @dtan, well I figured that the links the OP are talking about are all there on page load, and the content that's being loaded via AJAX is only further information relating to a link, not more links.

Comment: the links are being generated when the page loads.

Comment: ah, ok, if the links are on the page already and not being dynamically created, then `.click` is fine.

Comment: @Guided33, my suggestion is to generate the links in the PHP, and so they will be there on page load. But if you have to generate the links via javascript, then just do a `.wrap()`, but that doesn't prevent you from using `.click()` as long as you bind the click after the wrap. `.live()` is for binding to links that come in the HTML from the AJAX request, which I didn't think there would be any.